# How to map multiple joined tables into new tables with different column names

Tags: python, sql, database, oracle

So my organization is supplying data to another organization which requires the data to match a particular schema, but the required data is spread across multiple tables with different field names.

I've made a crosswalk of the corresponding fields (i.e. LOCATION_ID -> STATE_ID) where they apply, and some fields don't exist in our data.  My question is conceptual as I'm not sure what the best approach is. 
Any pointers in the right direction would be helpful.
I'm most familiar with Python and was thinking of using a Pandas script or an R script to rework the data and export to a new table, but I'm sure there's a more elegant solution in standard SQL or t-SQL.

Edit:

An example per suggestions:

Source Table

SITE_USE
UNKNOWN
ELEVATION
ELEV_METHOD
ELEV_DATUM

New Table

Well Type
Well Water Level Recorder Indicator
Land Surface Elevation Value (ft)
Land Surface Elevation Method
Land Surface Elevation Datum

Comment: Oracle <> tsql. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. ([mcve])

Comment: pandas, numpy and python are a step in the right direction for customized solutions. You may want read "python data science Handbook" from vanderPlas on this topic to guide you in detail.

Comment: Thanks @jarlh I added some detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking of a *view*.

In Oracle, there's Scott's sample schema which contains tables about employees and departments. A simple query, with no mapping for any columns, looks like this:

```
SQL> select e.deptno, d.dname, e.empno, e.ename, e.job, e.sal
  2  from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
  3  where d.deptno = 10;

    DEPTNO DNAME               EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- -------------- ---------- ---------- --------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING           7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
        10 ACCOUNTING           7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
        10 ACCOUNTING           7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300

SQL>
```

Now, if you can (why couldn't you?) create such a query for YOUR tables, a simple option is to create a  **view** and do the column mapping. For example, the same column set as above:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_emps as
  2  select e.deptno as dept_number,
  3         d.dname  as dept_name,
  4         e.empno  as employee_id,
  5         e.ename  as employee_name,
  6         e.job,
  7         e.sal    as salary
  8  from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno;

View created.

SQL>
```

Finally, it is a matter of a simple query to fetch data you need and provide it to whoever needs it, with brand new column names:

```
SQL> select * from v_emps
  2  where dept_number = 10;

DEPT_NUMBER DEPT_NAME      EMPLOYEE_ID EMPLOYEE_N JOB           SALARY
----------- -------------- ----------- ---------- --------- ----------
         10 ACCOUNTING            7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
         10 ACCOUNTING            7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
         10 ACCOUNTING            7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300

SQL>
```

No additional mapping is required; perform any kind of query, it'll do:

```
SQL> select * from v_emps
  2  where job = 'CLERK';

DEPT_NUMBER DEPT_NAME      EMPLOYEE_ID EMPLOYEE_N JOB           SALARY
----------- -------------- ----------- ---------- --------- ----------
         10 ACCOUNTING            7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300
         20 RESEARCH              7876 ADAMS      CLERK           1100
         20 RESEARCH              7369 SMITH      CLERK            800
         30 SALES                 7900 JAMES      CLERK            950

SQL>
```

---

If it is MS SQL Server you use (regarding T-SQL you mentioned), no problem either; there are views there as well.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Query is straight forward to join tables with `alias` column names

```
  SELECT C.Id AS Identifier, C.LastName + ', ' + C.FirstName AS CustomerName
 FROM Order O JOIN Customer C ON O.CustomerId = C.Id
```

Here `Order` is one table and `Customer` is another table
Each table has an alias identifier `O` and `C` correspondingly
 `CustomerName` is a non existing columns made from two columns
`Identifier` is a alias name given for `Id` from `Customer` table which is `C.Id`

Same way you can join another table and so on

`ON O.CustomerId = C.Id` means both customer table and order tables has same data in that column